# Processing OpenGL drawing issue

Tags: opengl, processing

I am trying to export a gif from processing but whenever I add OPENGL to the size parameters as is necessary, a line on the screen is not drawn. This occurs when attempting to draw points. If I draw an ellipse over the line the ellipse is rendered.

image of undrawn line
[image: image of undrawn line]

```
import gifAnimation.*;
import processing.opengl.*;
GifMaker gifExport;
void setup(){
  size(500,500,OPENGL);
  frameRate(12);
  println("gifAnimation " + Gif.version());
  gifExport = new GifMaker(this, "exported1.gif");
  gifExport.setRepeat(0);
}
float frame=0;
float noiseer(float x,float y){
    float d=TWO_PI/5.0*(y%5.0);
    float r=0.5;
    return noise(x/2,sin(d)*r,cos(d)*r)*2;
}
void draw(){
  frame++;
  if(frame<200){
  background(0);
  int z=0;
  stroke(255,0,0);
for(int x=0;x<500;x++){
  for(int y=0;y<500;y++){
    float xf=x-250;
    float yf=y-250;
    z=(int)((pow(noiseer((xf+100)/40.0,(yf+frame*5)/200.0)*2.0,2)*255/5));
    stroke(abs(z)*z,z*0.6,0,100+z);
    //stroke(255,0,0);
    point(x,y);
  }
}
  if(z!=0){
  gifExport.setDelay(1);
  gifExport.addFrame();
  }
}else if(frame==200){
  gifExport.finish();
  println("gif saved");
}
}
```